# Capturing Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON event

Tags: android, events, audio, bluetooth

I'm developing a Android audio application. Now, I'm capturing 
and playing audio with sucess and I want to add a new feature, the  capture and playing  through bluetooh headset.

I have been reading about that, and seems that I must manage the ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON 
event:

**Java file:**

```
....

public class audioBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) 
        {
            Log.d("","@@@@ WORKS" );
        }
        else
    {
    Log.d("","@@@@ ????" );                      
}
....
```

**xml file**

```
....
<receiver android:name="audioBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>     
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON">
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

But nothing happens, so, somebody  may give me a example or a idea for:

1º Know when the bluetooh has been connected.

2º Routed the audio packets through bluetooh headset.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need the bluetoothAdapter method.
    BluetoothAdapter blueT = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaulAdapter();

```
// create broadcast receiver
BroadcastReceiver blueReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
// todo switch states to turn on or off or check is on
// check is on is something like this:
case (blueT.STATE_ON) : {
 // do something with it
}

if(blueT.isEnabled()){
do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't works, also, I need to capture ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON